# Why are all Delegate types incompatible with each other?

Tags: c#

In C# all delegate types are incompatible with one another, even if they have the same signature.  As an example:

```
delegate void D1();
delegate void D2();

D1 d1 = MethodGroup;
D2 d2 = d1;                           // compile time error
D2 d2 = new D2 (d1);                  // you need to do this instead
```

What is the reasoning behind this behaviour and language design decision.

Comment: I cannot give you the reasoning, but delegates were an original language feature.  Since then, they have added lambda methods, [Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) and [Funcs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) which do not suffer from the same problem.

Comment: @Brandon What? Lambdas are converted to delegates (or expression trees) and `Action`s and `Func`s *are* just delegate types, so they follow exactly the same rules.

Comment: Delegate invocations are checked at runtime too.  That was optimized, an important kind of optimization, only strict type identity is supported.  That's fast.

Comment: @svick The difference is Actions, Funcs, and lambda expressions *implicitly* get converted to the delegate type you assign them to, even allowing for slightly different signatures, which was what the OP was complaining about.

Comment: @Brandon There really isn't anything special about `Action`s and `Func`s, they work *exactly* the same as any other delegate type.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> In C# all delegate types are incompatible with one another, even if they have the same signature. What is the reasoning behind this behaviour and language design decision?

First off, I think that it is fair to say that many of the runtime and language designers regret this decision. Structural typing on delegates -- that is, matching by signature -- is a frequently requested feature and it just seems strange that `Func<int, bool>` and `Predicate<int>` can't be freely assigned to each other.

The reasoning behind the decision as I understand it -- and I hasten to add that this decision was made about six years before I started on the C# team -- is that the expectation was that there would be delegate types with *semantics*.  You want this to be a type error:

```
AnyFunction<int, int> af = x=> { Console.WriteLine(x); return x + y; };
PureFunction<int, int> pf = af;
```

A "pure" function is a function which produces and consumes no side effects, consumes no information outside of its arguments, and returns a consistent value when given the same arguments.  Clearly `af` fails at least two of those, and so should not be assignable to `pf` as an implicit conversion.

But semantics-laden delegate types never happened, so it's a bit of a misfeature now.

Comment: I'll have to remember that term, '*misfeature*'.

Comment: I'll remember with fondness the short time I had an answer with more votes than Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 15):

Basically because the compiler makes two classes for you. The same reason you can't do:

```
class A {}
class B {}

void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = a;
}
```

---

For example, the following code

```
void Main() {}

delegate void D();
class C {}
```

The IL code is:

```
D.Invoke:

D.BeginInvoke:

D.EndInvoke:

D..ctor:

C..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

Answer (score 2):

Delegate is nothing but just another type. They are incompatible for the same reason `class A {}` and `class B {}` would be incompatible.

```
delegate void D1();
```

Will approximately compile to something like:

```
class D1 : MulticastDelegate { .... }
```