# Why a `Predicate<T>` doesn't match a `Func<T,bool>`?

Tags: c#, function, delegates, predicate

I try to compile the following code in C#:

```
public static T FirstEffective(IEnumerable<T> list) 
{
    Predicate<T> pred = x => x != null;
    return Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(list, pred);
}
```

The compiler (Mono/.NET 4.0) gives the following error:

```
File.cs(139,47) The best overloaded method match for `System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<T>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>,System.Func<T,bool>)' has some invalid arguments
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
File.cs(139,47): error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `System.Predicate<T>' expression to type `System.Func<T,bool>'
```

This is rather strange since a `Predicate<T>` is in fact a function that takes as input a parameter `T` and returns a `bool` (`T` is even "covariant" thus a specialization of `T` is allowed). Do delegates do not take the "Liskov Substitution principle" into account to derive that `Predicate<T>` is equivalent to `Func<T,bool>`? As far as I know this equivalence problem should be decidable.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665494/why-funct-bool-instead-of-predicatet

Comment: This is related, but does not explain why equivalence checks are not performed. As argued, the equivalence of delegate types is decidable...

Comment: As an aside to your question: Is it in fact known that the C# type system is not Turing complete? Is it a requirement that a type system be Turing-complete for it to be undeciable? The general problem of subtyping is undecidable; this paper might interest you: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64041/fool2007.pdf. When it was written C# did not yet have contravariance but it does now, so the bits about the IL language apply to C# 4.0.

Comment: @EricLippert: Sorry, the words were indeed chosen poorly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C# specification is clear about that:

> **15.1 Delegate declarations**
>
> Delegate types in C# are name equivalent, not structurally equivalent.
> Specifically, **two different delegate types that have the same
> parameter lists and return type are considered different delegate
> types**.

That's why your code doesn't compile.

You can make it work by calling the delegate, instead of passing it:

```
public static T FirstEffective (IEnumerable<T> list) {
    Predicate<T> pred = x => x != null;
    return Enumerable.FirstOrDefault (list, x => pred(x));
}
```

Comment: Still wondering why that is. Since the conversion between delegates is quite trivial: there is no real transformation. The same "method pointer" would be sufficient.

Comment: That's exactly the difference between method pointers and C# delegates. It's the same with `class`es: two classes with the same set of members are not considered equivalent. That's how type system in .NET works.

Comment: Eric's blog link is dead. Best I could find was using archive.org https://web.archive.org/web/20160331233359/http://blog.coverity.com/2014/06/18/delegates-structural-identity/

Comment: Eric Lippert has an answer about the same topic [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17215626/2638227).

Answer (score 6):

Delegate types are not implicitly convertible, even when they have all the same parameter and return information.  There is an easy workaround for your case though.  You can use the `.Invoke` method on your delegate instance.

```
public static T FirstEffective<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    Predicate<T> pred = x => x != null;
    return Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(list, pred.Invoke);
}
```

As to the question of why delegates work this way, the answer is that it was a design decision.  Classes that have identical public interfaces aren't implicitly convertible either, so it's not really inconsistent.

Comment: That's a nice solution. But it's rather strange that delegates are not considered to be equivalent...

Comment: yes but that's because they have different fields,... and it is not trivial how to convert them. A `List<T>` that uses an array is completely different from a list that uses a `LinkedList<T>` approach.

Comment: If I make two classes that each only have a `public string Foo { get; set; }`, I won't be able to use them interchangeably even their definitions are identical.  I see this as being a similar case.

Comment: yes @recursive is right - this is a common behaviour in OOP languagues - the name of a class/interface/etc. matters, not the signature.

Comment: @recursive: there is a difference: the programming code in C# is Turing complete. It is thus undecidable to check if two classes are identical (of course this trivial example can be checked). The type system however is not Turing complete, thus one can check if two signatures are identical...

Answer (score 1):

Quite belated but coincidentally I stumbled up on the same question and the accurate answer can be found here: [important comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453311/lamda-works-in-findall-but-not-when-using-it-as-an-func-or-expression/33454081?noredirect=1#comment54697457_33454081)

Basically it means that it's an inconsistency based on an unfortunate decision to implement it this way. Whilst `predicate<T> == func<T, bool>`, they are different types despite the same signature. I suppose for reasons of backward compatibility one can convert an expression and/or lambda and then return a predicate through `new predicate<T>(func<T, bool>)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the predicate worked when applied to a list using enumerable

```
  List<Product> products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product {ProductID=1,Name="Kayak",Category="Watersports",Price=275m},
                new Product {ProductID=2,Name="Lifejacket", Category="Watersports",Price=48.95m},
                new Product {ProductID=3,Name="Soccer Ball", Category="Soccer",Price=19.50m},
                new Product {ProductID=4,Name="Corner Flag", Category="Soccer",Price=34.95m}
            };

Predicate<Product> predicate = x => x.ProductID==4;

            var query=Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(products,x=>predicate(x));

            if (query != null) { 
                output.WriteLine(query.Name);
                Assert.True(true);
            }
```